# In Pyramid, using traversal, how do create dynamic urls?

Tags: python, traversal, pyramid

I am new to Pyramid and have created an application. I have a database with a table of categories. A category might be color with the attributes Red and Green, and another category might be size with the attributes 4 and 5.
I'd like to be able to create links that are like: domain.com/{category}.
So let's say I have two category templates. One is color.mak and one is size.mak. How would I get it so domain.com/Red or domain.com/Green would render color.mak and domain.com/4 or domain.com/5 would render size.mak?
After reading the differences between URL Dispatch and Traversal, it seems like Traversal would be preferred for what I want even though it could be done either way. What I'm really stuck on is how to add these categories to my resource tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll want your Root resource to return different resource types from `__getitem__`:

```
class Root(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in ['Red', 'Green']:
            return ColorCategory(key)
        elif key in ['4', '5']:
            return SizeCategory(key)

class ColorCategory(object):
    ...

class SizeCategory(object):
    ...
```

Then in your __init__.py, you'll want to configure different views for your different resource types (a.k.a. context types):

```
    config.add_view('myapp.views.color',
                context='myapp:resources.ColorCategory', name='',
                renderer='myapp:templates/color.mak')

    config.add_view('myapp.views.size',
                context='myapp:resources.SizeCategory', name='',
                renderer='myapp:templates/size.mak')
```

The way this will work is that when you get a certain URL, Traversal will look up a certain context and view name. For domain.com/Red, the context will be `ColorCategory('Red')` (because that's what your Root resource returns) and the view name will be `''` (because the path is totally consumed after looking up that context). Then pyramid will use the context type and view name as filters to find a configured view and template.